# Headers above entries in bar chart with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to produce something like the following graph ([source](https://thorax.bmj.com/content/75/9/735#F3)) with ggplot. (I do not care at this stage about the colors or other aesthetic details, nor about the data, just about reproducing the overall layout.)

[image: the expected result]

Here is my closest result.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggh4x)

df <- tribble(
  ~group, ~level, ~value, ~attribute,
  "g1", 0, 1, "attr1",
  "g1", 1, 2, "attr1",
  "g1", 0, 0, "attr2",
  "g1", 14, 3, "attr2",
  "g1", 16, 4, "attr2",
  "g2", 0, 3, "attr1",
  "g2", 1, 1, "attr1",
  "g2", 0, 0, "attr2",
  "g2", 14, 2, "attr2",
  "g2", 16, 3, "attr2"
)

ggplot(df, aes(x = interaction(level, attribute), y = value)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  ggtitle("Title") +
  facet_wrap(~group) +
  coord_flip() +
  guides(y = "axis_nested") +
  xlab("") +
  ylab("Marginal utility")
```

[image: result]

I would prefer to display the attribute names on top (rather than on the side) of the attribute levels. In other words, I would like to have "attr2" on top of 16 and "attr1" on top of 1. I couldn't find how to do that.

A solution that does not consider two groups would also be useful if managing two groups is incompatible with my goal. Using something else than ggplot2 is acceptable as well if ggplot2 cannot achieve this goal.

Answer (score 2):

One potential solution is to use `facet_grid()` instead of `facet_wrap()` and {ggh4x}, and then change the way the facet labels look for the y-axis:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tribble(
  ~group, ~level, ~value, ~attribute,
  "g1", 0, 1, "attr1",
  "g1", 1, 2, "attr1",
  "g1", 0, 0, "attr2",
  "g1", 14, 3, "attr2",
  "g1", 16, 4, "attr2",
  "g2", 0, 3, "attr1",
  "g2", 1, 1, "attr1",
  "g2", 0, 0, "attr2",
  "g2", 14, 2, "attr2",
  "g2", 16, 3, "attr2"
)

ggplot(df, aes(x = value, y = factor(level))) +
  geom_col() +
  ggtitle("Title") +
  facet_grid(attribute~group, scales = "free_y", switch ="y") +
  ylab("") +
  xlab("Marginal utility") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(plot.background = element_rect(
          fill = "transparent", colour = "transparent"
        ),
        axis.text.y = element_text(margin = margin(r = -25)),
        strip.text.y.left = element_text(
          angle = 0, face = "bold", vjust = 1
          ))
```

which gives:

[image: bar chart]

Comment: Thanks, but my main problem with my original attempt is still there: it wastes horizontal space. I would like to stick "attr1" and "attr2" closer to the y axis, thus, on top of 1 and 16, respectively. In particular when my labels are larger than just two digits, it makes a big difference.

Comment: Edited to put the facet strip text inside the axis and play with the margins to move the text underneath.

Comment: Great! Any idea how to adjust the margin automatically in order not to have to try-and-error? I suppose that it should be the width of the longest strip text?

Comment: Though quite effective, this is more of a workaround than a solution, so I opened an [issue](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/5344) in case an officially supported solution could be developed. (To no avail.)

Answer (score 1):

Here is trick that you might pull to get the effect you're after. It assumes 3 things:

1. You want this on the y-axis.
2. Your strip labels are wider than the y-axis text.
3. You don't particularly care deeply about the right-most margin of the strip and axis text: the spacing between the tick marks and labels.

First, we'll define a new text theme element that just re-classes `element_text()`.

```r
library(ggplot2)

element_text_zerowidth <- function(...) {
  el <- element_text(...)
  class(el) <- c("zw_text", class(el))
  el
}
```

We can then use this class to write a custom S3 method for `element_grob()`. We fool ggplot2 into thinking that this text has no width.

```r
element_grob.zw_text <- function(...) {
  grob <- NextMethod()
  grob$widths <- rep(unit(0, "pt"), length(grob$widths))
  grob
}
```

Now as long as the strip titles are longer than the axis text, you can use this new element to draw zero-width axis text, which will make the strip labels adjacent to the axis. Note that we remove the margin of the strip text here, since distance from the axis line to the text is now determined by the tick length.

```r
library(tibble)

df <- tribble(
  ~group, ~level, ~value, ~attribute,
  "g1", "some reference level", 1, "some long strip text",
  "g1", "another level", 2, "some long strip text",
  "g1", "zero units", 0, "another long strip text",
  "g1", "many units", 3, "another long strip text",
  "g1", "even more units", 4, "another long strip text",
  "g2", "some reference level", 3, "some long strip text",
  "g2", "another level", 1, "some long strip text",
  "g2", "zero units", 0, "another long strip text",
  "g2", "many units", 2, "another long strip text",
  "g2", "even more units", 3, "another long strip text"
)



ggplot(df, aes(x = value, y = factor(level))) +
  geom_col() +
  ggtitle("Title") +
  facet_grid(attribute~group, scales = "free_y", switch ="y") +
  ylab("") +
  xlab("Marginal utility") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(strip.placement = "outside",
        strip.text.y.left = element_text(angle = 0, face = "bold", vjust = 1, margin = margin()),
        axis.text.y.left = element_text_zerowidth())
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-07-06 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>